# Can we hide VB.NET first selection column?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I hope I state my problem correctly. Kindly please look at the screenclip below :'
[image]

I prefer that the first column shown above is not displayed. Is there any design/programmatic way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Edited :
Using this link http://www.andreavb.com/forum/viewtopic_7951.html, I am able to remove the triangle from the selection column

Comment: Hello. How did you change the appearance of your window form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is using a DataGridView I assume?  Just use the visible property for the row headers.

```
dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Alternatively, you can set it to false using the Properties window.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it. No, that's not the solution. It will hide the column `Kode`, which is one of our data :)

Comment: Oh, you said you wanted to hide the first column.  That's even easier.  In the DGV properties you can turn the row headers off.  Gimme a second and I'll find out which one...

Comment: Thanks! you're right! It is `RowHeaderVisible`. I thought it will hide completely the header row, but actually it only hide the first row that I wanted. Btw, have you looked at my another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201009/in-vb-net-can-we-draw-empty-lines-instead-of-blank-area-in-non-existent-row-of ?? Thanks