# In VB.NET, can we draw empty lines instead of blank area in non existent row of datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

EDITED:
I think we can just draw an image that resemble the grid using this article : [drawing in a datagridview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Datagridview_BackImage.aspx) Currently creating a way to make the image drawn in tile mode. :)

Each time I develop a datacentric application using VB.NET regardless of how much the data displayed in the datagrid, I always want the grid to display full row of empty data, not just blank panel.

Can we achieve this using VB.NET design time property?

And also, we must not trigger the display of vertical scrollbar this way.. :)
Thanks

[image: Empty lines]

Answer (score 1):

You might try doing a screen capture of the dgv when it is full of blank lines and use that as your background.  However, you'll have a problem with the vertical lines if they resize the columns.  In your picture you don't have any vertical lines so if you don't need them then just erase them and your problem is solved.

There's also the option of using the Virtual Mode.  When you set that property to true then you can set the number of visible rows, but you are responsible for telling the dgv what each individual cell is supposed to contain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx

Or you can just add extra blank rows to whatever datasource you are setting your DGV to.

Use the ScrollBars property to turn the vertical scroll bar off.

Comment: ... there might also be a paint event you could use to draw the lines yourself but I'm not sure which one you would use.  All the ones I can think of would only let you draw to rows that are already there.

Comment: you're right. If they resize it, it could be trouble. I found the right article, that maybe the solution for this problem. Here it is : http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1435.aspx About to test the code. Ow, but that is commercial third party controls I think

Comment: My first choice would be to pad the DataGridView's datasource with extra records and just manage how many there should be myself.  However, that's not ideal for all scenarios.  Painting the lines yourself shouldn't be that *difficult* at all, but it probably will be somewhat time consuming to implement if you've never overridden the paint method for a control before.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am posponed my solution for the drawing of these extra lines. There are still other higher priority tasks. Thanks!

Comment: @swdev yup, I know how that goes :)